# missing jruby gem for logstash

Tags: jruby, logstash

I have downloaded the latest logstash 1.4, and when I run it with the following config:

```
input {
  eventlog {    
  }
}
output { stdout {} }
```

I get this error :

```
D:\logstash-1.4.0\bin>logstash agent -f simpleConfig.config -l logs.log
Sending logstash logs to agent.log.
←[33mUsing milestone 2 input plugin 'eventlog'. This plugin should be stable, bu
t if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugi
n milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/plugin-milestones {:level=>:war
n}←[0m
LoadError: no such file to load -- jruby-win32ole
       require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1085
       require at file:/D:/logstash-1.4.0/vendor/jar/jruby-complete-1
.7.11.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.
rb:55
       require at file:/D:/logstash-1.4.0/vendor/jar/jruby-complete-1
.7.11.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.
rb:53
       require at D:/logstash-1.4.0/lib/logstash/JRUBY-6970.rb:27
       require at D:/logstash-1.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/poly
glot-0.3.4/lib/polyglot.rb:65
      register at D:/logstash-1.4.0/lib/logstash/inputs/eventlog.rb:3
7
  start_inputs at D:/logstash-1.4.0/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:135
          each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
  start_inputs at D:/logstash-1.4.0/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:134
           run at D:/logstash-1.4.0/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:72
       execute at D:/logstash-1.4.0/lib/logstash/agent.rb:136
           run at D:\logstash-1.4.0\lib\logstash\runner.rb:190
          call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271
    initialize at D:/logstash-1.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud
-0.0.17/lib/stud/task.rb:12
```

I think that the package win32ole jruby is missing, but I don't know how to add it.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 6):

I installed the `logstash-contrib-1.4.x.tar.gz`. 
I didn't found a download link so I copy the logstash download link and add "-contrib" in the filename eg: https://download.elasticsearch.org/logstash/logstash/logstash-contrib-1.4.2.tar.gz
This works fine in my case. 
The installation is only unzip the file on home directoy and override all files. Now it works.